# Laravel Ajax post on edit route

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i have a error about an Ajax post call, i use this Ajax to call for a list of zip code ,the Ajax call work fine if i use it on create.blade but don't work when i use it on edit.blade this is my code.

route

```
  Route::resource('cotizaciones', CotizacionController::class)->names('admin.cotizaciones');
  Route::post('getcp', [CotizacionController::class, 'getcp']);
```

controller

```
    public function getcp(Request $request){
        $gedataCP = CodigoPostal::where('cp', '=', $request->cp)->get();
        return $gedataCP;
    }
```

and this one is my Ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
    },
});

$("body").on("keyup", "#codigopostal", function () {
    var cp = "cp=" + $.trim($(this).val());
    var check = $.trim($(this).val());
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 5) {
        if(!/[a-z]/i.test(check)){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "../getcp",
            data: cp,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".overlay-wrapper").show();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#colonia").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#colonia").empty();
                $("#colonia").append(new Option("Selecciona una Colonia", ""));
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    $("#colonia").append(
                        new Option(item.asentamiento, item.asentamiento)
                    );
                    $("#estado").val(item.estado);
                });
                $("#colonia").append(new Option("Otra", "otro"));
                $("#estado").val(data[0].estado);
                $("#city").val(data[0].municipio);
                $(".overlay-wrapper").hide();
            },
        });
    }
    }
});
```

if i use this Ajax on create blade it work without a problem  but when i use it on my edit blade i got

**The POST method is not supported for route admin/cotizaciones/getcp. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.**

any ideas what im doing wrong Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok guys i solved it the url for the call was wrong, because im using external js file, my path was wrong, i had to edit my blade to add

```
<script>
    var routeURL = '{{ url('/') }}';
</script>
```

and change my ajax url to

```
url: routeURL+"/admin/getclienteid",
```